# Create Node system in game c# Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for create a something like this** but inside the game, not in the node Editor***. I see a lot of script for creating this but not directly inside the scene. I'm a beginner, and I have difficulties to create something like this, somebody can help me ?

[image: ** image here : https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmAqa8NZaRR-CcM7OCn6AUXLEC_ZNVDgf1XKGMFAy5i1aOmgVx]

[image]

ps : Sorry for my english ^^'

Comment: @Brandon he never said he wanted to use the Node System for programming, he said he wanted to use it for something in his game.  The screenshots are an example of what is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like [repurpose Unity's Mecanim system](https://medium.com/the-unity-developers-handbook/dont-re-invent-finite-state-machines-how-to-repurpose-unity-s-animator-7c6c421e5785).

Comment: This is exactly not what he wants, he wants the node system -in the build- not in the editor. Some ingame UI solution that is.